# How to debug incoming requests from android emulator

Tags: php

I am building a hybrid app with cordova. The backend is written in php. 
In the browser I am able to debug incoming requests (Here I use http://localhost:8000/myapi). 
In the android emulator not (Here I use http://10.0.2.2:8000/myapi).

I also tried to add "XDEBUG_SESSION" as request parameter but this also did not work.

How can I debug my php code if the incoming request source is the android emulator?

Comment: Please consider reformatting this question to remove the Cordova and Ionic tags and adding PHP tags, as your question is regarding how to debug PHP and it's not relevant if the client is a Cordova app, or anything else. I'd also look at existing questions on how to debug a PHP web API. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465570/how-to-debug-a-web-service-written-in-php

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to solve this problem. Dont add `XDEBUG_SESSION` but `XDEBUG_SESSION_START`.
Full example:

```
http://10.0.2.2:8000/myapi?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM
```

This way PHPSTORM will stop at the breakpoints.